# display image stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, tags, src

I have images that are base64 encoded as blobs in my sql database.

using a php script I can properly display the picture in my browser using.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $fetch_row['object']. '" />';
```

however,  I would like to create a view that would display the photo directly or by accessing the php file and returning the picture in a column.  I have tried using something like: in mysql

```
concat('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,',`object`,'" />')
or concat('<img src=/image.php? blah blah blah)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Image should store in directoy instead of database to skip slow process

Comment: I would recommend re-thinking this strategy. Store the image in a directory and store the image filename in the database. Storing images as BLOBs is slow and will make your db huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo base64_decode($fetch_row['object']);
```

Your question also exactly typifies why storing images in the database is a BAD idea. If the image was just a file on your server's drive, you could just have

```
<img src="/path/to/file.jpg" />
```

and not have to involve the DB/PHP layer at all. As it stands now, your data-uri version prevents the browser from caching that image at all, and you'll be forcing the user to download that image EVERY time, burning up their (and your) bandwidth.

Comment: You can cache database-backed content if you set the proper headers on the response, but with static content and the right configuration your web server will do it for you automatically.

Comment: not when that db-backed content is stuff into the body of a page, so that there's no independent link back to the server via that data. e.g. stuffing a 10meg image a base64-encoded data uri forces the browser to try and suck down a 10+meg page every time, if that page itself is set to not be cached. the browser has no way of knowing that the 10+megs of image data SHOULD be cached.

Comment: Do you know of a reliable php script that can save the image and create the url that references it in mysql? ---> echo base64_decode($fetch_row['object']); I replaced my echo line with the one you posted and it worked perfectly.

Comment: you save the image on your server somewhere, and store the path to the file in the database. e.g. just a simple string `/path/to/file`

Comment: thanks Marc for all your help.  These images are auto uploaded to the database.  usually a few hundred at a time from various user devices.  I would need a script that can save the files and automatically insert the url into the database.

Comment: @MarcB Who would stuff a multi-MB image into a `data:` URI? It wouldn't matter where that image came from, be it database, filesystem, or whatever, because you'd be doing it *wrong*. The whole point of having a remote URI is to promote caching, and this can be done regardless of the source.